# simple Doctrine query builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

I'm new in Symfony & Doctrine. Cannot understand how to write a queryBuilder.
In plain SQL either of two:

```
select c.*, s.result
from client c
 inner join score s on c.id = s.client_id;

select c.*, s.result
from client c, score s where c.id = s.client_id;
```

I tried the following from ClientRepository:

```
$clients = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->select('c')
    ->innerJoin(Score::class, 's', 'with', 's.client = c.id')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Don't see the score.result data .
Relation Client<=>Score is OneToOne
So how to return array of Client objects with appended result property ?

Entities:

Client:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ClientRepository")
 */

class Client
{
    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email(
     *     message = "The email '{{ value }}' is not a valid email."
     * )
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type(
     *     type="numeric",
     *     message="The value {{ value }} is not a number {{ type }}."
     * )
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 11,
     *      max = 32,
     *      minMessage = "Your phone number must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
     *      maxMessage = "Your phone number cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters",
     *      allowEmptyString = false
     * )
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $processData;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Education")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $education;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSurname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    public function setSurname(string $surname): self
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setPhone(string $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProcessData(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->processData;
    }

    public function setProcessData(bool $processData): self
    {
        $this->processData = $processData;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEducation(): ?Education
    {
        return $this->education;
    }

    public function setEducation(?Education $education): self
    {
        $this->education = $education;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Score:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ScoreRepository")
 */
class Score
{
    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $result;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Client", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $client;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getResult(): ?int
    {
        return $this->result;
    }

    public function setResult(?int $result): self
    {
        $this->result = $result;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getClient(): ?Client
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    public function setClient(Client $client): self
    {
        $this->client = $client;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

So how to return array of Client objects with appended result property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal Symfony & Doctrine way would be to change that Client - Score association to be [bidirectional](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional) instead of your current unidirectional.

Updating your Client entity side:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Score", mappedBy="client")
 */
private $score;

public function getScore(): ?Score
{
    return $this->score;
}

public function setScore(Score $score): self
{
     $this->score = $score;

     return $this;
}
```

And your Score entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Client", inversedBy="score" cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $client;
```

And then you don't need to write any specific query builder. When you have the Client object available, you can just call the getter to fetch the associated Score object.

```
$client->getScore();
```

Comment: You meant @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Score", mappedBy="client") not Results ?I don't have 'Results entity'. and probably not $client->getResult() but new $client->getScore().result ?

Comment: Yep, Score instead of Result - sorry. I assume that you got the idea already but I updated the answer accordingly.